# Error with nparray while converting Nan to 0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is my code:

```
prices = np.array(df[['1r_start', '1r_end', '2r_start', '2r_end', '3r_start', '3r_end', '4r_start', '4r_end', '5r_start', '5r_end', '6r_start',
```

'6r_end', 'studio_start', 'studio_end']])

It has a type = np.ndarray

And then if I try this part of code:

```
prices = np.nan_to_num(0)
```

Type of prices becomes np.int64

Shape of array is (1121,14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

`prices = df.to_numpy(dtype=int)`

this will convert your data frame to a numpy array and by precising the type as `int` it will fill the `na` values with the int's Null value which is 0. See [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) for more information.